# How to create a breakpoint in bochs?

Tags: c, assembly, bochs

I have read the object file with objdump and here theres a bit of my result:

```
    Disassembly of section .text.main:

00100000 <main>:
  100000:   8d 4c 24 04             lea    0x4(%esp),%ecx
  100004:   83 e4 f0                and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
  100007:   ff 71 fc                pushl  -0x4(%ecx)
  10000a:   55                      push   %ebp
  10000b:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
  10000d:   57                      push   %edi
  10000e:   56                      push   %esi
```

If want to insert a breakpoint in the 10000a address how I can do that from bochs command line?

I have tried things like: b 0x10000a or vp 0x10000a
And when I press (c) it does not stop on the breakpoint.

Thanks

Comment: Make sure you have not made a typo. In your dump you have **4** zeroes but in your command only **3**. Also reconsider if you need to use bochs for this. Why not just a debugger like `gdb`?

Comment: Still the same @Jester

Comment: I assume `vp` is another typo, as that should be `vb`. According to bochs help, the format is `seg:offset` so maybe you need to specify the segment too. You could try `lb` for a linear address instead.

Comment: Are you sure that code is actually loaded into memory at that virtual address inside BOCHS?  It looks like you're viewing disassembly from an object file, not a process in memory.  If you have 32-bit code with a function called `main`, you're probably running it under an OS with debugging facilities; like Jester suggests `gdb` is probably easier.  But if that's actually part of a kernel, then maybe check your page tables!  Single-step from some early point as you switch into protected mode, maybe?

Comment: Is this an OS development question and were you trying to be Multiboot compliant (run with griub)? If so you have some other problems. If this is for Linux/MacOS or Windows that entry point for `main` looks rather suspect.

Comment: If these code run under real mode, you should use `pb 0x10000a`. Or you can use [magic breakpoint](http://bochs.sourceforge.net/doc/docbook/user/bochsrc.html#AEN2422).